# Angularjs search is too slow while enter inside searchbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `angularjs` for search filter. I have multiple records in my application. But it is not getting slow to display data. It is working very fine.

I have a search functionality to filter the data. For Example,

I have the following records,

```
    "New Logic Data Starts"

    "New Data Server"

    "Server records found new"

    "Welcome to angularjs"
```

- ) If I am going to search " New" in a searchbox, It will show the first 3 results. These cases are working in my application. But it is taking minimum 5 seconds to enter the next letter in the textbox.
- ) Same as backspace also, if i remove "w" letter in a text "New", i need to wait 4 or 5 seconds to remove the next letter "e". AGain I need to wait and need to remove "N".

```js
if($scope.search){
        return $scope.search.split(' ').every(function(search){
            return card.Tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        });
      }else{
        return true;
      }
```

```html
<input type="search" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Search Card" ng-model="search">
```

Here, "card.Tag" is, card is list of Datas in my response and Tag is field for search results.

For Example,   `"Tag": "\"New Logic Data Starts\",\"New Data Server\",\"Server records found new\",\"Welcome to angularjs\"",`

Here, everything is working fine for me. But only thing is its very slow. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `angularjs filters`.

```js
(() => {
  let myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
    let records = ["New Logic Data Starts",
      "New Data Server",
      "Server records found new",
      "Welcome to angularjs"
    ];

    $scope.records = records;
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="filterString">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="r in records | filter: filterString">
        {{r}}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use this, only normal search will work. Please read my post. It should work random search and reverse search also. My code will work in all way. But only thing is it is making slow

Comment: We will need to see your entire code to find performance optimization opportunities. We need to see how the `filter` function looks like, how it is bound to the input field etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement your own code to search with lower case. AngularJs filters are more advanced and very fast. I have a set of JSON data with 8000 objects and the angularJs filter can search it within just 400 milliseconds.

```
ng-repeat="o in records | filter: searchString"
```